# jQuery load() : How to prevent pictures from down the page to appear first?

Tags: jquery

Clicking on a link loads (with jQuery load function) pictures in some , but I see the last pictures first for a brief moment as if they were loaded first, then the first pictures appear and stay.

How to prevent the last pictures of the loaded page from briefly appearing first ?

Comment: @drake035 is this what you're looking for : [`lazyload`](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use css `display:none;` as default beginning for images. And make them visible using jquery, after document ready.

Comment: Or even better yet, use `visibility: hidden` so that your other content doesn't shift around to fill all the "holes" you'd otherwise create with `display: none`

Comment: 1. images are not loaded in DOM ready. 2. He's loading the images with `ajax` request.

Comment: Then he can make images visible in the success callback of ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

For the pictures you don't want to appear first, add the class "noshow":

```
<img src="..." class="noshow" />
```

And this style:

```
.noshow{ display: none; }
```

Then using the callback from the load function:

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function() {
  $(".noshow").removeClass("noshow");
});
```

You can also use the ".show()" method, put the styling directly in the img tag, etc. if you want it to be more condensed.